# Twillio framework compression issue while pushing the code to github

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, twilio

I am creating one project using Twilio framework for creating the conference room, I integrated framework manually as guided in Twilio documents link "https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/ios" its working fine able to create room and everything working fine but when trying to push the file to GitHub its stuck with compression error. it's not Github problem as I am able to push related files (View Controller changes) and also framework size is 153MB can this be an issue. 
Screenshot attached with the error message
[error message while pushing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSocK.png)
[Twilio framework files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gBVm.png)

**Edit** I have also tried with git commond line. Problem is twilio exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 M Is there any other way I can add twilio framework or can I remove unwanted files and then just drag and drop required files?

I am using Xcode 8.3.3 and Gitbox and Twilio version1.x

Comment: Have you tried using the command line tool `git` to push the code up to GitHub? It could just be a problem with Gitbox compressing large files?

Comment: I tried that also getting same error file exceeds 100MB is there any other way I can add Twilio video framework, I can't user pod, can't update pod currently, do you support Carthage? can't I just drag Twilio files in my project? PS error mesage "remote: error: File TwilioVideo.framework/TwilioVideo is 148.92 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anyone has same issue you can temporary add Twilio/video file in ignore files while pushing the code on Github and then while pull can manually add that file in Twilio framework file, 
I know this is hectic and time-consuming but you will not be stuck and anyway, you don't want to push and store such big file in your repository. Just and the comments in the code so if another developer is working on the same branch can follow the same steps.

**PS:** Always use cocoa-pods instead of manual. I have to do it manually   because of some other cocoa-pods lib was getting updated, #so many code changes and I had time constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In the case where you can't use CocoaPods there is a file size issue. While there's nothing that can be done about this right now (sorry!) we are aware of the issue and want to fix it. I can't promise any timeline, but we are going to work on supporting Carthage, which should solve this for you.

I'll try to let you know when this support is released.